# Mode Calculation Using Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, mode

I am trying to calculate a mode by groups within Teradata. Below is what has been recommended:

```
select retl_a
from vpp_fpp
group by dpci_lbl_t
qualify rank() over (order by count(*) desc) = 1;
```

But I receive an error saying *Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group*. Any help is appreciated.

Below is an example:

```
data vpp_fpp
dpci_lbl_t retl_a
a 4
a 4
a 3
b 3
b 1
Expected result:
a 4
b 2
```

Comment: Actually - I think the provided solution might work, and work very well if I am able to get a count of records that have the varying values of retl_a WITHIN each dpci_lbl_t. Then I could do a query to identify the retl_a with the max count value. But I am trying to figure how I would incorporate it.

Comment: Gordon's code works as expected, of course it will return multiplw rows with the same max count. If you want to get only a single (random) row you can either switch to `ROW_NUMBER`, add another column to partition by or do a `SELECT dpci_lbl_t, AVG(retl_a) FROM Gordon's query` to get the average of tied values (which is a strange interpretation of *mode*)

Answer (score 1):

```
select retl_a
from vpp_fpp
group by dpci_lbl_t
qualify rank() over (order by count(*) desc) = 1;
```

Your initial query returns the "non-aggregate values" error because you are just returning a value "retl_a" without doing any aggregate computation on it.  You can either do something like MAX(retla_a) or move it to your GROUP BY clause.

To get your mode...first you need to get your number of rows per (dpci_lbl_t, retl_a) combo.  You can try something like this (similar to a previous answer):

```
SELECT dpci_lbl_t, retl_a, COUNT(*) Count_per_pair
FROM vpp_fpp
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Then you need to add your QUALIFY to get the pairs with the highest occurring frequency.  Something like this:

```
SELECT dpci_lbl_t, retl_a, COUNT(*) Count_per_pair
FROM vpp_fpp
GROUP BY 1, 2
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY dpci_lbl_t ORDER BY Count_per_pair) = 1;
```

To handle the case of a tie...you can wrap that around another SELECT and just take the AVERAGE of the sub-select's "retl_a" mode values:

```
SELECT dpci_lbl_t, AVERAGE(retl_a) AS MyMode
FROM (
    SELECT dpci_lbl_t, retl_a, COUNT(*) Count_per_pair
    FROM vpp_fpp
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY dpci_lbl_t ORDER BY Count_per_pair) = 1
) src
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Keep in mind, aggregates (i.e. MAX/COUNT...GROUP BY) and their HAVING clauses are processed before window functions (i.e. RANK(), ROW_NUMBER()) and their QUALIFY clauses.

To sum up:

1. The COUNT/GROUP BY functions get the number of rows per (dpci_lbl_t, retl_a) combination.  This represents how often each "retl_a" value occurs per "dpci_lbl_t" group.
2. The RANK() function then partitions the resulting rows by "dpci_lbl_t", orders them by the "Count_per_pair" value, and assigns a ranking based on that value.
3. The QUALIFY then filters out that result, only returning rows with RANK() = 1.  Think of it as a WHERE clause for window functions.
4. The AVERAGE() in the outer SELECT returns the "mode" values, including an average for any ties.

I don't have access to a TD system to verify, but give it a try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `partition by`.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
select dpci_lbl_t, retl_a
from vpp_fpp
group by dpci_lbl_t, retl_a
qualify rank() over (partition by dpci_lbl_t order by count(*) desc) = 1;
```

Comment: The code executes well - but it does not provide the mode for each particular category of dpci_lbl_t. So for example, let us assume there are 5 different values within retl_a for a particular dpci_lbl_t, then the query needs to return the mode or most often occurring value across all 5. The query currently returns multiple answers for different values of dpci_lbl_t. The only complication I can see if there are ties. For example, using my 5 values of retl_a, two could be $4, two could be $5, and one could be $6. Then it would give two answers $4 & $5, or simply take the average of the tie.

Comment: You really need to add some sample data and desired results to your original post.

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggestions to my original post Andrew. Thanks.